# connect sequelize.js to node-webkit desktop app using sqlite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, sequelize.js, node-webkit

currently I am using node-sqlite3 sqlite binding on my [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) desktop app and using it as

```
var sqlite3 = require('node_sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('file:data.db');
db.run(query);
```

and on my knowledge this natively compiled node-sqlite3 is the only way to use sqlite db with node-webkit.

now I want to use [sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) on the app which is normally used as:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize-sqlite').sequelize
var sqlite    = require('sequelize-sqlite').sqlite
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
dialect: 'sqlite',
storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite'
})
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM myTable").success(function(myTableRows) {
console.log(myTableRows)
})
```

how can I achieve this ? (ie. use sequelize on node-webkit app with sqlite)

the goal is to make the database life easier by running migrations , use models to manipulate database , or suggest if there are any other javascript libraries (mvc is prefered) , which can work through node-webkit+sqlite (and how to make them work) .

is angularjs an option ? if yes how to do this.

thank yous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. after using following sqlite3 for node-webkit and rebuilding it as in the

[node sqlite 3 for node-webkit](https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3/)

 It creates a folder named "node_sqlite3" inside the node_modules . I renamed "node_sqlite3" to "sqlite3". and then did npm-install of sequelize-sqlite . 

after this sequelize-sqlite automatically recognizes and gets connected to sqlite3 and it can normally be used.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize-sqlite').sequelize
var sqlite    = require('sequelize-sqlite').sqlite

var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', '', {
dialect: 'sqlite',
storage: 'file:data.db'
})

var Record = sequelize.define('Record', {
name: Sequelize.STRING,
quantity: Sequelize.INTEGER
})

sequelize.sync()
.success(function(){
console.log('synced')
})

var rec = Record.build({ name: "sunny", quantity: 3 });
rec.save()
.error(function(err) {
// error callback
alert('somethings wrong')
})
.success(function() {
// success callback
console.log('inserted')
});
```

and the records are in the database.

Comment: I'm doing a similar project, using Sequelize+sqlite3 in a node-webkit application.  In regards to defining the `sequelize` instance, what's the relative path for the `storage` option?  Where, relative to the app root (`package.json` and `index.html`) does the database go?

Comment: @MikeTrpcic I am still developing the app so currently sqlite db is inside the app folder but it must go outside the compressed app once it is complete , couldn't figure it out yet , will surely share if i find a way.

Comment: I did what you said and I'm getting this error =S `"Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './binding/Release/node-v11-darwin-ia32/node_sqlite3.node'", source: module.js (343)`Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem connecting to SQLite database from `node-webkit` using `sequelize`. By trial and error, I have come with the following solution.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite:mydb.sqlite3', {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: './mydb.sqlite3'
});

sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM tableName", { type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT })
.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(function (e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Note that for SQLite database you have to specify

```
storage: './mydb.sqlite3'
```

This is the path to your db file. It can be either absolute path or relative. `./` means project root folder where `package.json` is located.

Also, the connection string must contain the `sqlite:` prefix. Otherwise, it will raise an exception: `Cannot read property 'replace' of null`. The part after `sqlite:` prefix is irrevelant and can even be omitted because the actual db location is specified in `storage` option. `dialect` option can be omitted as well, since db type is mentioned in the connection string prefix. So you can connect simply using

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite:', {
  storage: './mydb.sqlite3'
});
```

It is also worth noting that `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated. At the time of writing this post, the latest version of Sequelize (3.21) uses `.then` method to handle operations if the promise is fulfilled and `.catch` method if the promise is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

In Node-WebKit you can you use modules written totally in JavaScript. For modules containing C/C++ you should build the addons by **[node-gyp](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Using-Node-modules#3rd-party-modules-with-cc-addons)** because the ABI (application binary interface) of node-webkit differs from Node's ABI.

Try smth like **[sequelize-sqlite](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-sqlite)** that 100% JS or find modules in npm go to it GitHub repository and under row **commits, branch, releases & contributor** click coloured row "Show language statistic".

Comment: I can use node-sqlite3 only because I already have build it by node-gyp and I am already using sequelize-sqlite as says the question . thank you for the answer anyway .